# C++ Builder hide items on Form when editing

Tags: c++builder

Is there any way to hide buttons and other things on your form when editing? I want to make like very expanded Interface and in one place there can be up to a few buttons at once so it's impossible to work like this without hiding other buttons. "Visible" variable is working only when running a program so i have no idea what to do... Any ideas?

EDIT: can you make it INVISIBLE not only send it to back?

Comment: Sounds like you are making your UI too complicated, or you are setting up things at design-time that probably should be setup dynamically at run-time instead.

Comment: When I set components on a form's Visible property to false, they disappear. This is using FMX, with version 10.

Comment: put controls in a panel. finish the design of those controls and move the panel out of view (for example set control->Left = 3000). at run time, bring the panel back to view (Left = desired_value).

Comment: but I agree with the others... if it is too crowded for you, it is too crowded also for the users.

Answer (score 2):

By default, controls cannot be made invisible at design-time.  To "hide" a control, you would have to either:

1. remove it from the Form altogether
2. physically move it outside the bounds of its Parent control
3. put it on a TabSheet of a `TPageControl`, and then switch to a different TabSheet.
4. maybe find (or write) a custom component editor that can toggle a control's design-time visibility (there is a `csDesignerHide` flag in the `TControl.ControlState` property, which can be toggled via the public `TControl.SetDesignVisible()` method).

Answer (score 0):

As Remy said, you can't do that, in the IDE. Of course you can do it in code, at runtime, but that is no help at design time.

I would create different frames for each setup needed. You can edit these separately, which greatly reduces any dependencies. You can even give each frame methods to evaluate the input and properties that can be called from the main form.

Otherwise, you can use a PageControl, and put each setup on a different tabsheet. If necessary, you can turn of the tabs of the PageControl. This is what wizard dialogs often do.

Comment: I know about Frames but the problem is when you start new Frame it creates new window. I tried to find any way to make "Frame" without new window but i couldn't find it anywhere. If it's possible i would be very glad to know the solution :)

Comment: In the designer, it is separate, but it can more or less be used like a complex component. It is not a window.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody provided a custom TControl editor for that at, obviously you'll have to put that in a package project and right-click Install it (add/activate Win32 target to that package project first, else Install option won't appear on right-click):

https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/2787-addon-to-hide-single-visual-controls-in-form-designer/?tab=comments#comment-22178